# How to store Kafka messages in Redis as list items using RedisSinkConnector?

Tags: json, apache-kafka, redis, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to read messages stored in Kafka in JSON format and store them as list items in Redis using RedisSinkConnector. I have used the following configuration:

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8083/connectors/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '  {"name": "redis-sink",
   "config": {
     "connector.class":"com.redis.kafka.connect.RedisSinkConnector",
     "tasks.max":"1",
     "topics":"t_location",
     "redis.type" : "LIST",
     "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
     "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
 
}}'
```

The message stored in Kafka is in the following format:

```
key: car-three
value: {"timestamp":1683742700544,"distanceFromBase":104,"car_no":"car-three"}
```

I expect the message to be stored in Redis as follows:

```
LPUSH car-three {"timestamp":1683742700544,"distanceFromBase":104,"car_no":"car-three"}
```

However, the command that is printed in Redis is set as follows:

"LPUSH" "t_location" "car-three"

Comment: There should be another command for `"LPUSH" "${value}" ...`. No? Also, why are you hard-coding `redis.key: ${key}`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer , When I leave redis.key empty, it is set with the topic name.sorry I did not understand your meaning of another command for "LPUSH" "${value}"...

Comment: I suggest checking the documentation. The examples do not use `${key}` - https://redis-field-engineering.github.io/redis-kafka-connect/#data-structures